# ionic 3- change android SDK Tools Version

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 3 project. It was build in Ionic 2 and later migrated to Ionic 3.
Now I recently changed the `cordova-android` version. It was fetching 6.3.0 by default.

So I removed the platform and added 7.1.0 by using the following command

```
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0
```

When I did `ionic info`. I got the following result.

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.6

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.12.0
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

I checked C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools

It doesn't have `26.1.1` version but it has `27.0.1` version but ionic info is still showing 26.1.1

How can I fix this issue? Thanks!